# bootstrap modal dialog not showing (black background showing)

Tags: jquery, html, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I have **two modal dialogs**(causing the issue) in the html file.

**Which ever modal dialog is placed first in the sequence of the html file, shows properly on button click (vice-versa).**

Both modal dialogs have unique id's and are invoked appropriately, yet one modal dialog doesn't show up (if invoked later on-separately).

```html
     <!-- Modal dialog xyz is the first in the sequence of html code -->
     <div class="modal fade" id="xyzModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="xyzModalTitle" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
          .....
        </div>
     </div>

     <!-- Modal dialog abc is the second M.D in the sequence of html code -->
     <div class="modal fade" id="abcModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="abcModalTitle" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
          .....
        </div>
     </div>
```

Where exactly am I going wrong in invocation of the modal dialogs.

For the corresponding button clicks, I am using hide/show functions as well, but is not working.

```js
     $("#xyzModal").modal('hide');
     $("#abcModal").modal('show');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try bellow code. It's working.** use the bellow cdn and script.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test Modal</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>

    <!-- Button trigger modal -->
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#xyzModal">
        Launch xyzModal modal
    </button>

    <!-- Button trigger modal -->
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#abcModal">
        Launch abcModal modal
    </button>

    <!-- Modal dialog xyz is the first in the sequence of html code -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="xyzModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="xyzModalTitle" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
            .....
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Modal dialog abc is the second M.D in the sequence of html code -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="abcModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="abcModalTitle" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
            .....
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#xyzModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
            //
        })

        $('#abcModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
            //
        })

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to hide all modals before you open a new one, then the best to do is:

```
$(".modal").modal('hide');
$("#abcModal").modal('show');
```

This ensures that **all** modals are hidden before you open a new one.

Comment: Yes I did try hiding all modals first (and showing either one of them). The issue still persists